# Python JSON key error, but key matches

Tags: python, ansible

Novice programmer trying to get dynamic inventory from Solarwinds into Ansible.  I'm connecting to Solarwinds via rest and have the data I need.  When I run the script I get a key error.  I dont get why as I see the key it's indicating is wrong.

Here's the code:

```
import os
import sys
import argparse
import ConfigParser

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

import requests

payload = 'query=SELECT+TOP+10+IPAddress,+Vendor+FROM+Orion.Nodes'
url = "https://10.150.199.44:17778/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Query"
req = requests.get(url, params=payload, verify=False, auth=('ansible', 'pass'))

jsonget = req.json()

    def get_list(self):
        hostsData = jsonget
        print "Test json before manipulation:\n"
        print(hostsData)
        print "\n\n"
        if hostsData['Vendor'] == []:
            print ''
        else:
            for rows in hostsData['Vendor']:
                print 'hosts:' + rows['IPAddress']
```

Here is my output:

```
./swinds.py --list
Test json before manipulation:

{u'results': [{u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.190.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.250.3'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.255.255.42'}, {u'Vendor': u'Juniper Networks/NetScreen', u'IPAddress': u'10.58.1.1'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.1'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.3'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.4'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.6'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.7'}]}



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./swinds.py", line 75, in <module>
    SwInventory()
  File "./swinds.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.inventory = self.get_list()
  File "./swinds.py", line 57, in get_list
    if hostsData['Vendor'] == []:
KeyError: 'Vendor'
test@ubuntu:/etc/ansible$
```

Why am I getting this error?  Thanks for any help.

CB

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Nope, it's a list stored against `results`. So `hostsData['results'][0]['Vendor']` gets the first result.

Comment: Ahh yep you are correct, missed the bracket

Comment: You're probably on Python 2. The string in the `dict` is unicode (indicated by the `u`) while you try to retrieve just `'Vendor'` which is an ASCII encoded string, i.e. a series of bytes. Try using `u'Vendor'` instead.

Comment: @a_guest it doesn't make a difference. The issue is that the OP is trying to access nested elements without using the appropriate chain of keys and indices to get at it.

Comment: Roganjosh, that totally did it!  I was thinking the results was the problem but had no idea how to account for it.  I'm not clear on one item, what does the [0] do? Is that the indice?  Also do you have an idea on solving the next error: 

print 'hosts:' + rows['IPAddress']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a JSON object, you have a python dictionary created from JSON. I don't know how you got to the point that you show in your example, but JSON is readily interchanged between python lists/dicts and actual JSON. How do I know it's not JSON? You have the unicode `u` in front of the strings and single quotations e.g. `'` instead of `"`. Ultimately it doesn't matter when you're just working locally in Python, you can use them in the same way, but you should be aware of the distinction.

You have a dictionary with one key: `results`. That maps to a list as a value (which you can index), and each item in that list is a dictionary itself. If you want to print `hosts:` and the IP address (as suggested in your comment):

```
hostsData = {u'results': [{u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.190.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.150.250.3'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.255.255.42'}, {u'Vendor': u'Juniper Networks/NetScreen', u'IPAddress': u'10.58.1.1'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.1'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.2'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.3'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.4'}, {u'Vendor': u'Unknown', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.6'}, {u'Vendor': u'Cisco', u'IPAddress': u'10.33.93.7'}]}

for item in hostsData['results']:
    print "Hosts: " + item['IPAddress']
```

Comment: I added to my initial post how I'm getting the data into the variable hostsData.  What you did worked the problem I was trying to solve was getting the output of hosts to loop in Vendor field.  The vendor is the group and the IPAddresses are the hosts.  The final json has to look a certain way for Ansible to read it: 
`code`
{
    "Cisco"   : {
        "hosts"   : [ "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ],
        "vars"    : {
            "a"   : true
        }
 }
}`code`

Comment: Before you try to post your code.. the site works on a 1 question: 1 answer principle. You can't keep expanding the question. Did my answer solve your initial problem? If so, I would appreciate you marking it as correct to close this problem. If you have further problems, you need to raise a new question.

Comment: My bad.  New here.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries :) it just helps other people when they search specific issues in Google. I'm about to lose all connectivity; if you still face an issue and you cannot solve and raise a new question with no answer, nudge me here. Otherwise, best of luck :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot.